# laravel datatables filtering column not exist in database

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

how can I filter or sort column which been modified by controller to display another data, like this column for displaying vendor_id but from controller I edited this table to display name of the vendor_id, so I want to filter,sort the name now not the id!
I want to display all checkes information in the table, also I want to display the name of vendor, this name exist in Vendors Table, and vendor_id this exist in both checks and vendors tables, also want to show category name only which exist in excategories table and the category id is in checks table

I have 3 tables:

**Excategories model**

```
   public function checks()
   {
  return $this->hasMany(Checks::class);
    }
   public function vendors()
    {
  return $this->hasMany(Vendors::class);
 }
```

**Vendors model:**

```
    public function checks()
       {
    return $this->hasMany(Checks::class);
      }
     public function categories()
      {
     return $this->belongsTo(Excategories::class);
     }
```

**Checks model:**

```
   public function scopeBetween($query, Carbon $from, Carbon $to)
    {$query->whereBetween('postingdate', [$from, $to]); }

    public function vendors()
  {return $this->belongsTo(Vendors::class);}
   public function categories(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Excategories::class);}
```

**inputs in datatable:**

```
      var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
            dom: 'flBrtip',                   
            stateSave: true,
            paging:     true,
            pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
            lengthMenu: [ [10,15, 30, 50, -1 ], [ 10,15, 30, 50, "All" ] ],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                 url: 'custom-filter-data',
                    data: function(d) {
                          d.start_date = $('input[name=start_date]').val();
                           d.end_date = $('input[name=end_date]').val();
                         }
                         },
          columns : [


       {data: 'details', name: 'details'},
         { data: 'postingdate', render: function (data) {
            var date = new Date(data);
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
              return (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();} },

          {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
           {data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
          {data: 'type', name: 'type'},
        {data: 'vendor_name',mRender: function (data, type, row) {                   

    return '<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="vendor_name" 
      class="vendor_name" data-id="'+row.id+'" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">';}},

    {data: 'vendor_id', mRender: function (data, type, row) {                   
    return '<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="vendor_no" 
     class="vendor_no"  onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">';}},

  {data: 'category_id',mRender: function (data, type, row) {                   
    return '<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="category_name" class="category_name" data-id="'+row.id+'" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">';}},
           ],
           pageLength: 10,
           });
       oTable.draw();
```

**controller**

```
        public function getCustomFilterData()
         {
       $arrStart = explode("/", Input::get('start_date'));
        $arrEnd = explode("/", Input::get('end_date'));
        $start = Carbon::create($arrStart[2], $arrStart[0], $arrStart[1], 0, 0, 0);
        $end = Carbon::create($arrEnd[2], $arrEnd[0], $arrEnd[1], 23, 59, 59);

       $orders = Checks::between($start, $end);
       return Datatables::of($orders)
      ->editColumn('category_id', function ($user) { 
      $category =Excategories::where('category_id',$user->category_id)->first();
        return ( @$category->category_name);
       })
       ->editColumn('vendor_id', function ($user) { 
        $category =Vendors::where('vendor_id',$user->vendor_id)->first();
       return ( @$category->vendor_name);
      }) ->addColumn('vendor_no', '{{$vendor_id}}')
     ->make( TRUE );
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to filter data using database query you should join the checks table to the category table instead of editing column so you will have the category name in query result then you can filter it

example for vendor table:

```
 $vendorTableName= with(new Vendors())->getTable();
 $orders = Checks::select(["checks.*","vendors.name"])->between($start, $end)->join($vendorTableName,$vendorTableName.".vendor_id","=","checks.vendor_id");
```

and then for getting the name of vendor you can use vendors.name column in dataTable. the category name is also the same thing.

Comment: can you make this more clear? the main table is checks here , you mean I have to combine two databases?

Comment: you have to combine two tables with sql join : checks and category

Comment: I need a code for this I dont know how to use join while Im using datatable still new on this

Comment: i need more information about your database to be able to give you some code. how is checks table is related to category table?

Comment: Updated,please have a look

Comment: but on search i got error message
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'checks.vendorName' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `checks` inner join `vendors` on `vendors`.`vendor_id` = `checks`.`vendor_id` where `postingdate` between 1999-01-01 00:00:00 and 2017-12-31 23:59:59 and (LOWER(`checks`.`details`) LIKE %c% or LOWER(`checks`.`postingdate`) LIKE %c% or LOWER(`checks`.`description`) LIKE %c% or LOWER(`checks`.`amount`) LIKE %c% or LOWER(`checks`.`type`) LIKE %c% or LOWER(`checks`.`vendorName`) LIKE %c% or

Comment: check the new changes

Comment: The same problem only when search!!!!!   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'checks.vendor_name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `checks` inner join `vendors` on `vendors`.`vendor_id` = `checks`.`vendor_id` where `postingdate` between 1999-01-01 00:00:00 and 2017-12-31 23:59:59 and (LOWER(`checks`.`details`) LIKE %c% or LOWER(`checks`.`postingdate`) LIKE %c% or LOWER(`checks`.`description`) LIKE %c%

Comment: please send the javascript code that is setting the datatable columns

Comment: Solved: {data: 'vendor_name', name: 'vendors.vendor_name',mRender: function (data, type, row) {  ....
thank you